# Need to change Databasename in views dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We are migrating the server and the time of migration we are changing existing  databasename to new name. my problem is I have created multiple views and Procs in that database tables. Now I need to replace/modifi in all view/Procs with new database name. Is there any possibility to change or replace existing dn name to new db name in all views/procs in dynamiclly?

Comment: If you're database is in a database project, you *could* use a simple find and replace (`Ctrl+H`). I assume, therefore, you're saying the the views are referencing objects my 3 part name convention? If so, if the tables the views are referencing are in the same database, why are you not just using 2 part naming?

Comment: You could script out the procs and views and modify using the script dom. Here's [an example PowerShell gist](https://gist.github.com/guzmanda/3eaff9b1fa86da19b2a5f2a50cd16a95).

Comment: I can replace each view and altered. But I have 300 views I need to change the Databasename of the table

Comment: Eg : Previous we are using 'SELECT * FROM repo.dbo.Abc' and now we need to change 'SELECT * FROM report.dbo.Abc' . Where ever we use 'repo' db we need to replace 'report' in all views/procs but I know we can manually replace and altered the view/proc but I need is it possible to replace dynamically at single time

Comment: And there is your original problem. Don't use 3-part names without a GOOD reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this query, after get result run NewModifiedQuery column as a query

```
SELECT a.definition OldCreationQuery
    ,Replace ((REPLACE(definition,'OldDatabaseName','NewDatabaseName')),'Create','ALTER') NewModifiedQuery
FROM sys.sql_modules a

 where a.definition like '%OldDatabaseName%'
```